# Problem with select sort in C++ using swap

Tags: c++, sorting, const-correctness

I'm trying to finish this code, and right now I am facing a error with the Selection Sort Algorithm:

```
error: no matching function for call to 
‘swap(const std::vector<int>*, const std::vector<int>*)’
       swap(&adj[min_idx], &adj[j]);
```

and

```
invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘int*’ [-fpermissive]
    b = temp;
```

I have to sort the graph by the number of it's vertices degree. Can someone can help me? Thank you!

```cpp
void swap(int *a, int *b) {    
    int temp;
    temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}

void sortGraph(vector<int> const *adj, size_t count) {
    int size = count;
        
    //sort by degree, number of children
    for (int j = 0; j < size - 1; j++) {
        int min_idx = j;
        for (int i = j + 1; i < size; i++) {
            if (adj[i].size() < adj[min_idx].size())
                min_idx = i;
        }
        swap(&adj[min_idx], &adj[j]);
    }
}

void printGraph(std::vector<int> const* adj, size_t count) {
    std::vector<size_t> indices;
    for (size_t i = 0; i != count; ++i)
    {
        indices.push_back(i);
    }

    for (auto index : indices)
    {
        std::cout << "Vertex " << index << ", degree " << adj[index].size() << '\n';
    }
}
    
void addEdge(vector<int> adj[], int u, int v) {
    adj[u].push_back(v);
    adj[v].push_back(u);
}
   
int main() {
    int V = 5;
    vector<int> adj[V];
    addEdge(adj, 0, 2);
    addEdge(adj, 0, 1);
    addEdge(adj, 0, 3);
    addEdge(adj, 0, 4);
    addEdge(adj, 2, 1);
    addEdge(adj, 4, 1);
    //printGraph(adj, V);
    sortGraph(adj, V);
    return 0;
}
```

https://ideone.com/mgffaj

Answer (score 0):

Change the signature of

```
void  sortGraph(vector<int> const* adj, size_t count)
```

to

```
void  sortGraph(vector<int> * adj, size_t count)
```

You have previously declared that the *vector* is *const* which means you are not allowed to change it's contents. Swap requires you to be able to pass *non const* pointers to int but you are passing *const* pointers to int.

I suggest you read some articles on [const correctness](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness)

You also had a couple of other problems with the code. Your definition of swap would be better to take the integers by reference.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

void swap(int&a, int&b) {    
   int temp;
   temp = a;
   a = b;
   b = temp;
}


void  sortGraph(vector<int> * adj, size_t count){
  int size = count;
    
    //sort by degree, number of children
         for (int j = 0; j < size - 1; j++) {
            int min_idx = j;
            for (int i = j + 1; i < size; i++) {
              if (adj[i].size() < adj[min_idx].size())
                 min_idx = i;
            }
            swap(adj[min_idx], adj[j]);
    
          }
            

}


void printGraph(std::vector<int> const* adj, size_t count)
{
    std::vector<size_t> indices;
    for (size_t i = 0; i != count; ++i)
    {
        indices.push_back(i);
    }

    for (auto index : indices)
    {
        std::cout << "Vertex " << index << ", degree " << adj[index].size() << '\n';
    }
}

void addEdge(vector<int> adj[], int u, int v)
{
    adj[u].push_back(v);
    adj[v].push_back(u);
}


int main()
{
int V = 5;
vector<int> adj[V];
addEdge(adj, 0, 2);
addEdge(adj, 0, 1);
addEdge(adj, 0, 3);
addEdge(adj, 0, 4);
addEdge(adj, 2, 1);
addEdge(adj, 4, 1);
//printGraph(adj, V);
sortGraph(adj, V);
return 0;
}
```

compiles now. I have not checked it for runtime correctness.

https://godbolt.org/z/4r1o9bjez

(ps I find godbolt more convienient for trying out snippets. YMMV )